# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in a .then() => { } with Firebase

Tags: react-native

Alright. So i'm new to react native and im learning on creating a signup authentication with Firebase. I have three files: Signup.js, Login.js and Profile.js. In my Signup screen when i call on the function handleSignUp onPress i get:

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.

I assume that i need to get out of the function scope to the global scope? I'm not sure what i'm missing here or how to tackle it. any advice?

Here's my code.

```
{*Signup.js*}
import React from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import Firebase from '../config/Firebase'

class Signup extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

    handleSignUp = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state
    Firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })}
                    placeholder='Full Name'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                    placeholder='Email'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Signup</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    inputBox: {
        width: '85%',
        margin: 10,
        padding: 15,
        fontSize: 16,
        borderColor: '#d3d3d3',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    button: {
        marginTop: 30,
        marginBottom: 20,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFA611',
        borderColor: '#FFA611',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        width: 200
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    buttonSignup: {
        fontSize: 12
    }
})

export default Signup
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Button } from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                    placeholder='Email'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Button
                  title="Don't have an account yet? Sign up"
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}
              />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    inputBox: {
        width: '85%',
        margin: 10,
        padding: 15,
        fontSize: 16,
        borderColor: '#d3d3d3',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    button: {
        marginTop: 30,
        marginBottom: 20,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F6820D',
        borderColor: '#F6820D',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        width: 200
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    buttonSignup: {
        fontSize: 12
    }
})

export default Login
```

Profile.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})

export default Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html

The current SignUp code is only a React.Component.

Make sure you're creating both an **AppNavigator** and **createAppContainer()** per react-navigation documentation.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: please let me know if thats enough